# How filter git cache

Tags: git

I want to move part of a repository into another repository.

So I clone repository into new directory, remove remote origin, filter files and directories, remove empty commits from history and call `git gc`:

```
$ git clone repo1 my_dir
$ cd my_dir
$ git remote remove origin
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf <some_files_and_dirs>' HEAD
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@"' HEAD
$ git gc
```

After all I see 3 commits with ~20 files and it's ok. But after all I also have:

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 36757
size: 1542676
in-pack: 39386
packs: 1
size-pack: 372300
...
$ du -h -d 2
du -h -d 2
 68K    ./src
1.8G    ./.git/objects
 64K    ./.git/info
8.0K    ./.git/logs
 48K    ./.git/hooks
  0B    ./.git/refs
```

How I can filter this ~2Gb of git objects? I trying:

```
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <some_files_and_dirs>' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But this didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps me:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='git update-ref -d %(refname)' | grep -v master | bash
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

After this action all is ok:

```
$ git log --all --oneline | wc -l
3
$ git count-objects -v
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 55
packs: 1
size-pack: 18
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

And `git rev-list --objects --all` contains only necessary data.